# Changing secrets of kiali in istio is not working

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks, kiali

I have deployed **istio** in my **eks** cluster with **demo** profile. **demo** has **kiali** deployment with it. The access secret for **kiali dashboard** is ( **username:admin**,**password:admin** ).I was able to access my dashboard with this credentials. Then I created my own secrets.

```
$ echo shajaltest | base64
$ c2hhamFsdGVzdAo=
```

Deleted the secrets for kiali.

```
$ kubectl delete secrets kiali -n istio-system
```

Deployed the secrets again with this **yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: kiali
type: Opaque
data:
  username: c2hhamFsdGVzdAo=
  passphrase: c2hhamFsdGVzdAo=
```

After all of that I deleted the pod of kiali.
After that I can not access my dashboard with this username and password. **What should I do ?**

I also checked the secrets of kiali. It has updated with recent secret value.

Here is the log of **kiali pod**.

```
I0408 18:30:30.194890       1 kiali.go:66] Kiali: Version: v1.15.1, Commit: 
3263b7692bcc06ad40292bedea5a9213e04aa9db
I0408 18:30:30.195179       1 kiali.go:205] Using authentication strategy [login]
I0408 18:30:30.195205       1 kiali.go:87] Kiali: Console version: 1.15.0
I0408 18:30:30.195212       1 kiali.go:286] Updating base URL in index.html with [/kiali]
I0408 18:30:30.195376       1 kiali.go:267] Generating env.js from config
I0408 18:30:30.197274       1 server.go:57] Server endpoint will start at [:20001/kiali]
I0408 18:30:30.197285       1 server.go:58] Server endpoint will serve static content from [/opt/kiali/console]
I0408 18:30:30.197297       1 metrics_server.go:18] Starting Metrics Server on [:9090]
I0408 18:30:30.197367       1 kiali.go:137] Secret is now available.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to follow the [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/#create-a-secret) about changing the credentials in kiali?

---

I made a reproduction of your issue with below steps and everything worked just fine.

> Enter a **Kiali username** when prompted:

```
KIALI_USERNAME=$(read -p 'Kiali Username: ' uval && echo -n $uval | base64)
```

> Enter a **Kiali passphrase** when prompted:

```
KIALI_PASSPHRASE=$(read -sp 'Kiali Passphrase: ' pval && echo -n $pval | base64)
```

> **To create a secret**, run the following commands:

```
NAMESPACE=istio-system
```

---

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
  labels:
    app: kiali
type: Opaque
data:
  username: $KIALI_USERNAME
  passphrase: $KIALI_PASSPHRASE
EOF
```

And simply recreate the kiali pod with

```
kubectl delete pod <name_of_the_kiali_pod> -n istio-system
```

---

**EDIT**

As @Shajal Ahamed mentioned in comments the problem was absence of `-n`, if you want to use just echo, then use.

```
echo -n username | base64
echo -n passphrase | base64
```

Comment: This is just istio documentation . I have done the same thing .Does not work .

Comment: Actually I tested the "echo" you used itself, and in fact it doesn't work, but if you follow steps provided by me, with KIALI_USERNAME and KIALI_USERNAME it's working, it's weird.

Comment: Just found the problem.  $ echo -n shajaltest | base64 . works. Thanks man....