# kiali dashboard login fails in istio demo profile

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kiali, istio-kiali

I have installed Istio as described [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/).

I used `istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo` for this purpose. And then installed `bookinfo` application.

And set kiali to use `NordPort` using `kubectl -n istio-system edit svc kiali`.

`kubectl -n istio-system get svc kiali` shows its `NordPort` and Ports `20001:32173/TCP`

When I try to access kiali dashboard using `192.168.123.456:32173/kiali`, with default username and password `admin` I get following warining.

> Your session has expired or was terminated in another window

Why is it happening? I haven't change any default settings.

Kiali pod is running.

As [jt97](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11977760/jt97) requested `curl -v externalIP:port/kiali`

```
*   Trying 192.168.123.456...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.123.456 (192.168.123.456) port 15029 (#0)
> GET /kiali/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.123.456:15029
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< accept-ranges: bytes
< content-length: 2330
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< last-modified: Mon, 04 May 2020 14:46:17 GMT
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< date: Mon, 04 May 2020 14:59:40 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 0
< server: istio-envoy
<
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><base href="/kiali/"/><script type="text/javascript" src="./env.js"></script><link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/><link rel="shortcut icon" href="./kiali_icon_lightbkg_16px.png"/><title>Kiali Console</title><link href="./static/css/2.51abb30a.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="./static/css/main.aebbfcdd.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body class="pf-m-redhat-font"><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script>!function(a){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],i=e[2],u=0,l=[];u<n.length;u++)t=n[u],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(p,t)&&p[t]&&l.push(p[t][0]),p[t]=0;for(r in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&(a[r]=o[r]);for(s&&s(e);l.length;)l.shift()();return c.push.apply(c,i||[]),f()}function f(){for(var e,r=0;r<c.length;r++){for(var t=c[r],n=!0,o=1;o<t.length;o++){var i=t[o];0!==p[i]&&(n=!1)}n&&(c.splice(r--,1),e=u(u.s=t[0]))}return e}var t={},p={1:0},c=[];function u(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var r=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return a[e].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,u),r.l=!0,r.exports}u.m=a,u.c=t,u.d=function(e,r,t){u.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},u.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},u.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=u(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var t=Object.create(null);if(u.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var n in r)u.d(t,n,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,n));return t},u.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return u.d(r,"a",r),r},u.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},u.p="./";var r=this["webpackJsonp@* Connection #0 to host 192.168.123.456 left intact
kiali/kiali-ui"]=this["webpackJsonp@kiali/kiali-ui"]||[],n=r.push.bind(r);r.push=e,r=r.slice();for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)e(r[o]);var s=n;f()}([])</script><script src="./static/js/2.f84a82a8.chunk.js"></script><script src="./static/js/main.339a2916.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

Kiali log : `/var/log/containers/kiali-869c6894c5-4jp2v_istio-system_kiali-1xxx.log`

```
{"log":"I0505 04:49:19.151849       1 kiali.go:66] Kiali: Version: v1.15.2, Commit: 718aedca76e612e2f95498d022fab1e116613792\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-05-05T04:49:19.152333612Z"}
{"log":"I0505 04:49:19.153038       1 kiali.go:205] Using authentication strategy [login]\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-05-05T04:49:19.153122786Z"}
{"log":"I0505 04:49:19.158187       1 kiali.go:87] Kiali: Console version: 1.15.1\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-05-05T04:49:19.158268318Z"}
{"log":"I0505 04:49:19.158210       1 kiali.go:286] Updating base URL in index.html with [/kiali]\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-05-05T04:49:19.158284789Z"}
{"log":"I0505 04:49:19.158840       1 kiali.go:267] Generating env.js from config\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-05-05T04:49:19.158915814Z"}
{"log":"I0505 04:49:19.168786       1 server.go:57] Server endpoint will start at [:20001/kiali]\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-05-05T04:49:19.168870138Z"}
{"log":"I0505 04:49:19.168813       1 server.go:58] Server endpoint will serve static content from [/opt/kiali/console]\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-05-05T04:49:19.16888486Z"}
{"log":"I0505 04:49:19.179424       1 metrics_server.go:18] Starting Metrics Server on [:9090]\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-05-05T04:49:19.179497168Z"}
{"log":"I0505 04:49:19.179752       1 kiali.go:137] Secret is now available.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-05-05T04:49:19.17998388Z"}
```

I found another error, which is not visible at once. When I enter username and password, it gives :

> You are logged in, but there was a problem when fetching some required server configurations, try refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in istio docs [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/#option-2-insecure-access-http)

If you want to acces kiali dashboard you should install your istio demo profile with `--set values.kiali.enabled=true`

```
istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --set values.kiali.enabled=true
```

Then apply virtual service, gateway and destination rule

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: kiali-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 15029
      name: http-kiali
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kiali-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - kiali-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 15029
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kiali
        port:
          number: 20001
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  host: kiali
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
---
EOF
```

Get your external-ip with

```
kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
```

And visit kiali via your browser with `http://<EXTERNAL-IP>:15029/`and credentials admin:admin.

---

Additionally if you want to change the kiali credentials check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107694/changing-secrets-of-kiali-in-istio-is-not-working/61116599#61116599).

Comment: What about curl? What you get from `curl -v http://<EXTERNAL-IP>:15029/`? Bookinfo is working through web? Could you add logs from the kiali pod to your question?

Comment: I have updated the question with `curl -v ` result.

Comment: What about if Bookinfo is working through web? Could you add logs from the kiali pod to your question? From the output it seems kiali is working properly, the code is 200 so it works, so I think the problem might be with the loadbalancer.

Comment: Yes, `bookinfo` works through web and `/productpage` shows expected round-robin behavior. I have added `kiali-log` file, but seems its now growing.

Comment: From the logs and curl we can see that everything works properly.  Your kiali service type is ClusterIP and port is 20001? It should work on 192.168.123.456:15029/kiali/ if you have follow yamls provided by me.

Comment: Yes, its `ClusterIP:20001`, it gives me the login prompt, but I can not access to it. It gives an error, which is not visible at once, I have updated the question with it.

Comment: My problem was with my PC time, it was different.

Comment: Which version of Istio are you using? 1.5.2? Have you tried to use the command istioctl dashboard kiali?